# How much does it cost to host an app in Azure Services App?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, service

I was checking Azure plans (specifically Service App) and didn't understand well their prices. I just want to upload a simple MVC .Net Core App (And create a SQL Database instance also in Azure) for a friend of mine.
This App it's just to manage his customers and products. Could someone tell me a final price in dollars?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a suitable question for SO. You need to do your own due diligence.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions regarding pricing of hosting produces are not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 2):

The answer would not be straight forward with a single figure. It is all around the compute power and storage (vPU, RAM, etc.) so it depends how many hours you would need these resources. [This pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/) is useful to give some indication, but not sufficient unfortunately (saying this by experience).

However you can easily calculate based on the the compute power and plans you think may be suitable that are given in the following links:

[App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/)

[SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/single/)

You should consider General Purpose and Serverless for SQL in order to reduce the cost. This off course has it's disadvantages which should be a different topic to discuss. Also, buying a one or more years up front saves cost!

Beware that prices do change.

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors you need to specify before you can find the cost. Like Region, OS, Tier etc. You can use [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/). Just search for service app, fill the details and you will know the expected price.